# How do I get ID of a submit type button on its click in Python + HTML + web2py?

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I am using WEB2PY framework

For example, I have a lot of submit type buttons on my webpage and when I click one I want to pass that specific clicked button ID from HTML to a Python variable.

Another problem is that when I use a Python variable inside of a SQlite insert statement then I am getting an error.

My HTML code:

```
<form method = "POST">
Case:
<input type="text" name="case_qty" value = 0><br>
Pcs:
<input type="text" name="pcs_qty" value= 0><br>
<button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
def fortune():
    case = 0
    pcs = 0
    proddict = {}
    productrows = db(db.products).select()
//my db contains product id & name
    for x in productrows :
             proddict[x.id]= x.product_name
    if request.post_vars:
         case = int(request.post_vars.case_qty)
         pcs = int(request.post_vars.pcs_qty)
         product= proddict[]//i want submitted button id number inside []
         sql = "insert into cart(product_name,case_qty,pcs_qty)values(product,case,pcs)"
        // another problem is when i use variable 
        //inside values i am getting error  
         r = db.executesql(sql)
return locals()
```

Comment: As with any html form element, it needs a `name` element of you want it to be submitted to the backend.

Comment: but even if i use name for button on click what is the code in python for getting the name of the button